# Release 6 is not found in the system - Creating a Project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have now a little experience in Java, so I wanted to take the next step to an IDE, so I installed the Eclipse IDE. (If it matters, I am using mac.)

But this does not seem to work right, as soon as I create a new class, the error occurs:

*The project was not built due to "release 6 is not found in the
system". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and
building it since it may be inconsistent    HelloWorld*

I already tried to change some of the properties in the class or selecting different settings, right now I use the execution environment JRE: J2SE-1.5.

Thank you for taking your time!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using such an old JRE?

Comment: If I use the latest version 12.0.1 I can't do anything, since I get an Building Error right after declaring the module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well it is basically telling you that you don't have the right version of Java **JDK** installed.  [THIS](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation) page seems to imply the current version of eclipse needs 1.8 - not the 1.6 you're talking about.  I am unsure though how you could have specified one that isn't installed.  Maybe you only have the JRE (java runtime environment).  You will definitely need the JDK (java development kit) because that is what has the java compiler in it.

It's been a long time since I used eclipse but when you created the project you should have been prompted to specify the java version.  Now try right clicking on the project and choose Build Path... Configure Build Path.  On the Java Compiler tab (left side) you should be able to change the configured Java to whatever you have installed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I switched to JavaSE-1.8. With that, the error does not occur any more, but instead I now get warned that there are no JRE's installed in the workspace. But I am pretty sure I installed an JRE, otherwise I could not run it from the editor, can I?

Comment: shoud I additionally install the 1.8 JRE or the whole 1.8 JDK?

Comment: Go to Window, Preferences, Java, Installed JREs and make sure it is added there

Comment: I have this problem with eclipse as well, however, I have JDK 12 installed which I believe is the newest version (right?) and when I first installed eclipse it worked fine. The error only showed up after restarting eclipse and to make it even weirder, my program runs perfectly fine even *with* this error. So I'm pretty sure this might be a bug of some kind. I don't see what I could be doing wrong and I've never gotten this error with eclipse before until installing the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when the selected version under *Preferences > Java > Compiler > Compiler compliance level* was higher than the selected version under *Preferences > Java > JREs > Installed JREs*. There was a small (very small) warning at the top of the JREs page warning me that there was an incompatibility with the compiler compliance level.

The options for compiler compliance level includes all versions up to the version that Eclipse itself is using, even if you don't have a specific JDK with that version, so you can get warnings for JDK releases that you definitely don't have.

I updated the compiler compliance level to be the correct version for my project and that got rid of the problem.